# Unable to show domain name instead of IP with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I configured a node.js api in digitaloceans and I'm trying to show mydomain.com instead of the IP Server using nginx. I have the following configuration in my default nginx config:

```
server {
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    listen server_ip:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /tmp/mycrt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /tmp/mykey.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://server_ip:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;}
}
```

I configured the domain record with domain_name A IP_Server. It redirects to my server but it change to https://server_ip instead of https://my_domain.com.

What I'm missing?
Thanks you.

Comment: You are missing out an return statement. Check the answer below and also the link in the ANSWER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it following this [guide](https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/serving-a-website-on-a-registered-domain-with-https-using-nginx-and-lets-encrypt-8d482e01a682)

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code in the config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # Listen to your server ip address
    server_name your-server-ip; 

    # Redirect all traffic comming from your-server-ip to your domain
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

For more details follow steps from [here](https://memorynotfound.com/nginx-redirect-ip-address-domain-name/).

Comment: Thanks, if I try to put this code, when I enter https://example.com it ask me to download a file (application/octet-stream), an empty file.